# accessing ng-if expression from sibling scope

Tags: angularjs

The ng-if attached to the footer element has expression "clicked" which when the app first starts I expect that it gets evaluated to false by angular.

When the button "class=menuLeft" is tapped, it's ng-click suppose to change the value of "clicked" to true as stated in headerCtrl menuToggle(), so that by clicking the button, the user can toggle the footer from shown to hidden and vice versa.
The code is not doing whats expected, please help. Thank you.

```js
//---headerCtrl.js--------------------------------
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('appModule')
        .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', HeaderCtrl]);

    function HeaderCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.menuToggle = menuToggle;
        function menuToggle() {
            $parents.clicked = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
//---index.html-----------------------------
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="appModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <base href="http://localhost:63342/angOne/">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="services/routing.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/mainMenuCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>
<header ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" ng-model="clicked" ng-click="menuToggle()">&#9776;</button>
    <label id="pageTitle" class="pageTitle">Select item from list</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<main ng-view></main>

<footer ng-if="clicked">
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
        <li><button type="button">NO</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">YES</button></li>
    </ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your controller scope is limited to the `header` elements - the `footer` is outside of the scope.

Comment: So what would be the best way to solve it? create another controller on the body element or use the global scope and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Header` and `Footer` have different scopes.

If you want them to communicate it could be via a common `service`:

```
angular
.module('appModule', [])
.factory('TogglerFactory', function($rootScope) {
  var TogglerFactory = {};

  TogglerFactory.menuToggle = function(){
    $rootScope.clicked = !$rootScope.clicked;
  }

  return TogglerFactory;
});
```

And then injecting that factory to the `Header` and `Footer` controllers:

```
   .controller('Header/Footer Ctrl', ['$scope', 'TogglerFactory', HeaderCtrl]);
      function HeaderCtrl($scope, Toggler) {
        $scope.menuToggle = Toggler.menuToggle;
      }
   }]);
```

Or by using `$rootScope`:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('appModule', [])
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', HeaderCtrl]);

  function HeaderCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.menuToggle = function() {
      $rootScope.clicked = !$rootScope.clicked;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="appModule">
  <header ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" ng-click="menuToggle()">&#9776;</button>
    <label id="pageTitle" class="pageTitle">Select item from list</label>
  </header>

  <main ng-view></main>

  <footer ng-if="clicked">
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
      <li>
        <button type="button">NO</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button">EXTRA</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button">YES</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: @FredJ. Added explanation on how it's done using a service.